# JavaScript Left Join on two JSON inputs in Logic App

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App which receives two datasets:

Dataset 1:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston"
    }
]
```

Dataset 2:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "age": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "age": "72"
    }
]
```

I want to apply a left join. I.e. Select all "userId" from Dataset 1 and only select matching "userId" from Dataset 2 and generate below output:

Output:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor",
        "äge": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "72"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston",
        "age": null
    }
]
```

I can do this with Logic App native actions; however, when the payloads are large, the Logic App takes hours to perform this job so I want to apply an Inline Code - JavaScript action to perform this. I am not a JavaScript developer so need a help with this please.

Comment: .map over the first array, use .find to find a match and if it exists, return the combined object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dataset1 = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston"
    }
]

const dataset2 = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "age": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "age": "72"
    }
]

const result = dataset1.map(item1 => ({
  ...item1,
  age: dataset2.find(item2 => item2.userId === item1.userId)?.age || null
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code bellow:

```js
const dataset1 = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston"
    }
]

const dataset2 = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "age": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "age": "72"
    }
]

const output = dataset1.map(x => {
    const result = dataset2.find(element => element.userId === x.userId);
    return {...x, age: result?.age || null};
})

console.log(output)
```